# When I start prepare kubernetes in aws the errors shown below

Tags: service, kubernetes, find

Below are the commands and their outputs:

```
root@k8s-master:~# sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
cp: cannot stat '/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf': No such file or directory
```

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl get services -n kube-system
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Comment: So... To be able to help you, we need you to help us... Just the error not knowing how you created your cluster won't help. Is it and eks cluster? What documentation are you using to create your cluster? If EKS, did you install the aws autenticator?

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you are not running EKS. Otherwise you cannot access the masters. With EKS, the masters are managed by AWS and you can't ssh to them
2. your kubectl commands makes a call to the kubernetes api server. So you have to check if it is running on localhost on port 8080.